# Switch Between Bootstrap Modals

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I have setup my rails 4 app to run with bootstrap 3 and devise.

I have customised the devise sign up and sign in views so that they are now inside bootstrap modals. However, despite using the shared items, which includes a "Not a member? sign up here" link, it doesn't appear in the login modal.

When I copy and paste that code directly in the modal, the register modal is displayed within the login modal. The buttons don't work and it looks awful.

Does anyone know how to create a link, for example "Not a member? sign up here" that will cause the login modal to close and the register modal to open?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [bootstraps modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) and scroll down to its methods option. You can see *how to manually hide and show* a modal by js.

`Does anyone know how to create a link, for example "Not a member? sign up here" that will cause the login modal to close and the register modal to open?`

**Fix:**

First of all you need to make sure that the *html of both register modal and login modal* are **present in your page** so that they both can be called up (I'm not sure but for this you may have to override devise methods but as your question is about hiding and showing modal so i wont go there).

Your link can be something like:

```
<%= link_to "Not a member? sign up here", class: "new_user" %>
```

and your js will look like this:

```
$(document).on("click",".new_user",function(){
  $('#id_of_sign_in_modal').modal('hide');
  $('#id_of_sign_up_modal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.  I actually amended the link to override the html (so that it did not reload the page on click). This works too:  <%= link_to('Not a member? sign up here', 'javascript:;', class: "new_user") %>

Comment: I'm doing something like this, but there's a minor problem. When the modal swaps, the new one shows up too early, so the Hide function still removes the `.modal-open` class from the `body` element, which isn't a problem most of the time, but is detrimental if the modal is long and scrollable.

Comment: the scroll active on main page, somebody solve this scroll problem?

Answer (score 6):

**Modal Switch Bootstrap 4 without Script**

> FIX: Does anyone know how to create a link, for example "forgot
>   password?" that will cause the login modal to close and the forgot
>   password modal to open?

You can simply switch modal using bootstrap attribute.

You just have add this code in button or any element which you want, data-dismiss will close your modal and the data-target will open your second modal, also you can check demo which link i have shared below.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Second_modal">Switch Modal</button>
```

https://codepen.io/shabbirvaghela/pen/rNVMBNJ

Comment: adding `$("body").addClass("modal-open")` solve the scroll problem as shown on the sample code

Comment: already added in this demo https://codepen.io/shabbirvaghela/pen/rNVMBNJ
it is bug from bootstrap side.